# Group By in LINQ with a particular column

Tags: c#, linq

I want my data in javascript such that it creates arrays for each fund and within those arrays there should be all the date and amount fields like

FundName1
dated amount
dated amount
dated amount

FundName2
dated amount
dated amount
dated amount

Or can I throw all the data to javascript and then doing this with with javascript? if Yes then How?

[image: I have data as shown in image]

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? It's quite hard to understand.

Comment: You should look up with `GroupBy` documentation. What you're asking is a fairly basic group by.

Comment: I have this data at CSharp level I want to group By it with FundName or Fund_ID  such that FundName appears only once and all dated and amount fields related to that FundName appears with in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in C#. Since every `Fund_ID` has a unique `Fund_Name`, it is safe to group by both columns:

```
var grouped = (from f in data
              group f by new { F.Fund_ID, F.Fund_Name } into grouping
              select new Class1()
              {
                  Fund_ID = grouping.Key.Fund_ID,
                  Fund_Name = grouping.Key.Fund_Name,
                  Details = grouping.Select(x=> new Class2()
                                     { Amount = x.Amount, Date = x.Dated }).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

Assumes you have classes:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Fund_ID { get; set; }
    public string Fund_Name { get; set; }
    public List<Class2> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible with eliminating 'Details' ?

Comment: @MaazKhan47 don't you want the amount and date for each `Fund_ID` ?

Comment: Okay Got it. So in model Details should be list? a list of which data type?

Comment: @MaazKhan47 it is *anonymous type* created on the spot here (google that to read more about it). You can create a class, but since you're passing this to JavaScript, who cares about creating a class :)

Comment: If you could please help me with anonymous type. How to declare ir in model and then how to use it in Controller?

Comment: @MaazKhan47 Oh you're passing that in MVC, create a class then and use: `Select(x=> new MyClassName() { Amount = x.A  ....`

Comment: This is LINQ Part:
 var graphData = (from dt in dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                           group dt by new { F = dt["FundName"] } into grp
                            select new vm_FundGraph
                           { fundName = grp.Key.F.ToString(),
                               Details = grp.Select(x => new { Amount = x["amount"], date = x["dated"] }).ToList()
                           }).ToList();

Comment: This is model
 public class vm_FundGraph
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        //public string fundID { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }

        public string fundName { get; set; }
}

Comment: @MaazKhan47 I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot @user3185569. I got it clearly :D :)